# break up dataframe into smaller pieces by date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, chunking

I have a large dataframe that of the following stats:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1819714 entries, 0 to 1819713
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Date_Time    datetime64[ns]
Open         float64
High         float64
Low          float64
Last         float64
Volume       int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(4), int64(1)
memory usage: 83.3 MB
```

I need to evaluate it but I do not understand how to chunk the dataframe.  I would like to break the dataframe into smaller chunch to apply a function to it, as the set it too large and crashes the notebook.  I have also tried:

```
temp=[]
for i,row in data.groupby(data["Date_Time"].dt.date):
    temp.append(myfunction(row))
```

but it keeps crashing or I get a memory exceeded error.   What is the best way to solve this issue?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the data(truncated):

[Sample Data for backtest](https://pastebin.com/k8dZrTTS)

The function, I am trying to perform is this below.  It runs fine when I slice it in small chunks, but I want the slices to happen either on a per day or month basis, since these are natural breaks for in the dataframe.
I tried to use a Datetimeindex, but the problem I have is that indexing back and forth does not work if the data in not in uniform time deltas.   I reindexed the main set of data, to allow for traversing the index.

```
data['exit_type']=np.nan
data['exit_price']=np.nan
data['Sreturn']=0
data['position']=0

def backtest(data, endtime=dt.time(16,0)):
    active_position = 0
    for i,row in data.iterrows():
        data.loc[i,'position']=active_position       
        if data.loc[i,'Signal']==1 and active_position==0:
            active_position=1 
            data.loc[i, 'exit_type'] = None    
        elif active_position>0:
            if data.loc[i,'High']<data.loc[i,'L1'] or data.loc[i,'Date_Time'].time()<endtime:
                if data.loc[i,'Low']<=data.loc[i,'boundary2']:
                    data.loc[i, 'exit_type'] = 'stop'
                    active_position=0
                    data.loc[i,'Sreturn']=(data.loc[i,'boundary2']-data.loc[i-1,'Close'])*active_position*50
                else:
                    data.loc[i, 'exit_type'] = None
                    data.loc[i,'position']=active_position
                    data.loc[i,'Sreturn']=(data.loc[i,'Close']-data.loc[i-1,'Close'])*active_position*50
            else:
                data.loc[i, 'exit_type'] = 'exit'
                active_position=0
                data.loc[i,'Sreturn']=(data.loc[i,'L1']-data.loc[i-1,'Close'])*active_position*50
```

so I try to use the groupby function to break up the chunks, but this is where it falls apart. since there are several conditions relying on other columns to control 'position', there doesnt seem to be a way to vectorize.  As one can see the 'Sreturn' is based on several other columns.

Comment: That is a relatively small dataframe.  The underlying issue probably resides with `myfunction`.

Comment: Looping over the rows of a DataFrame is rarely the most efficient way to do things with a DataFrame. I'm pretty sure you can accomplish what you want with `DataFrame.apply`.

Comment: The issue is that the my function is event based and I do not know of a way to vectorize.  I will update above to show the issue.